# Bootstrap's navbar-toggle seems to be incompatible with swipebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Yesterday I finally found out a lightbox that works on iPhones for my website (not using flash).
Everything is perfect, except for the navbar toggle that doesn't do anything when clicking on it. I think there might be a conflict between css and js files but I can't find out what... You'll find the code below.
Has somebody ever experienced such a problem ? Maybe those are not compatible to each other ?

Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial_scale=1.0">
  <link href = "css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script src="src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/swipebox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/swipebox.css">

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial_scale=1.0">
      <link href = "css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
      <script src="src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/swipebox.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/swipebox.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role='navigation'>
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified" style="margin-right:20px">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="whoami.php">Who am I ?</a>
                        </li>              
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <h2 class="page-header" style='color:black'>Gallery</h2>
        <section id="exemple" class="container">
            <div class="wrap small-width">
                <div id="try"></div>
                <ul id="box-container">
                    <li class="box">
                        <a href="img/1.JPG" class="swipebox" title="some text">
                            <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="image">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="box">
                        <a href="img/1.JPG" class="swipebox" title="some text">
                            <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="image">
                        </a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li class="box">
                        <a href="img/1.JPG" class="swipebox" title="some text">
                            <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="image">
                        </a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li class="box">
                        <a href="img/1.JPG" class="swipebox" title="some text">
                            <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="image">
                        </a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li class="box">
                        <a href="img/1.JPG" class="swipebox" title="some text">
                            <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="image">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="lib/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            /* Basic Gallery */
            $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();

            /* Video */
            $( '.swipebox-video' ).swipebox();

            /* Dynamic Gallery */
            $( '#gallery' ).click( function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.swipebox( [
                    { href : 'http://swipebox.csag.co/mages/image-1.jpg', title : 'My Caption' },
                    { href : 'http://swipebox.csag.co/images/image-2.jpg', title : 'My Second Caption' }
                    ] );
            } );

        });
        </script>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: remove this extra tag  </a> </li>...

Comment: Please create a self contained example that reproduces your issue. E.g. on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Dekkard, I edited my program so you can look at it again.